# Python. Сделать замену с помощью sub

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.
Как красиво и лучше сделать замену с помощью sub (мб и не sub?)?
Есть группы и в тексте надо заменить группы кортежом (22, 33, 'krasivo'), или словарем {t:22, t1:33, title='krasivo'}

```
pattern = re.compile('<label t="(?P<t>.*?)" t1="(?P<t1>.*?)" title="(?P<title>.*?)"')
```

текст <label t="36.79501866" t1="60.41651212" title="Jahmal TGK!!"/>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern = re.compile('<label t="(?P<t>.*?)" t1="(?P<t1>.*?)" title="(?P<title>.*?)"')
t='<label t="36.79501866" t1="60.41651212" title="Jahmal TGK!!"/>'
cort = (22, 33, 'krasivo')
t1 = re.sub(pattern, '<label t="{0}" t1="{1}" title="{2}"'.format(*cort), t)
```

Можно и справочник вместо кортежа. Тогда 0, 1, 2 заменяются на t, t1, title. Ну и вместо одной звёздочки -- две

Comment: Отлично, спасибо.
А если у меня большой список из многих строк <label **>, то можно будет сделать, что бы заменить их?
к примеру есть две строки и список из двух кортежей.
t='<label t="10" t1="20" title="Jahmal TGK!!"/> \n <label t="30" t1="40" title="ee"/>'
надо будет делать список из кортежей [(22, 33, 'krasivo'), (15, 60, 'three')], а как дальше?

Comment: Ну во-первых, то, что вы написали -- не пойдёт (можете проверить). Если у вас каждый тег label в отдельной строке, то обрабатывайте их по очереди. Если несколько в одной -- можете разбить на отдельные строки. Или использовать нормальные инструменты для работы с xml. С sax получается совсем неплохо (мне правда для более конкретного ответа надо много вспоминать -- давно это делал)

Comment: Хотя и с помощью регэкспов тоже не сложно, несколько строк. (Ну надеюсь, скорость обработки не важна. Иначе регэкспы побоку).
`m=pattern.search`, затем делить исходную строку `[:m.begin()]` -- то, что до шаблона, `[m.begin():m.end()]` -- строка для pattern.sub с подстановкой очередных значений, `[m.end():]` -- хвост для следующей итерации.

Comment: Понятно, лучше конечно по строке перебирать и проверять.
Спасибо )